# dmenu hide part of string

Tags: shell, sh, dmenu

I have this on a file:

```
github - https://github.com/search?q=
google - https://www.google.com/search?q=
pixabay - https://www.pixabay.com//es/images/search/
map - https://www.google.com/maps/place/
giff - https://giphy.com/search/
```

I want to get the first column on a dmenu list. I can get this by: `awk '{print $1}' file | dmenu` that gives me the first result(column), but I need to pass the las column (the actual url). In other words, I want to hide the url when launching `dmenu`. `Fzf` has an option that makes possible this very easy: `echo file|fzf --with-nth=1 | awk '{print $3}'`.

Comment: did you try passing the first word to dmenu, then grep the "dmenu answer" in your menu file and select the third field?

Comment: `a=$(cut -d ' ' -f1 base | dmenu -l 20 ) && grep $a base | awk '{print $3}'` The problem is when I have more than one result

Comment: try `grep "^$a -" base` to clamp the search to the start of lines and force the whole word thanks to searching the dash separator.